# Dynamic modal height with SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, simplemodal

I'm using SimpleModal to display a modal whose height needs to change in response to a dropdown list change in the modal that repopulates a portion of a dialog.  The problem I'm running into is that SimpleModal doesn't resize the height of the modal when the selection changes.

I've seen other posts on SO related to this but none of them seem to have a conclusive answer or are not directly related to my scenario (we're supporting IE 7 and 8).

Any guidance on this would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will help:

```
   $.modal(data,
    {
      minWidth: 400,
      onShow: function(dialog){
        //изменение размеров контейнера по размеру контена
        dialog.container.css({"height":"auto","width":"auto"});
      }
    });
```

Comment: I had a lot of other things in play to work around this.  This was the magic bullet for auto height.